# Optimizing runtime on finding the nth perfect power number

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

i was given a task to write a code to find the nth [perfect power number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power). i wrote the following function to find that number but the runtime is long at high number (above 30). 
you can assume that the input number is within the range of 1-100. 
here's the code:

```
def perfect(n: int) -> int:
    """
    :param n: enter the n'th place perfect power num you'd like
    :return: the n'th perfect power number
    """
    powers = []
    i = 1
    for i in range(0, n**2+1):
        for k in range(0, i):
            for m in range(0, i):
                if m ** k == i:
                    powers.append(i)
                    i += 1
                    break
        if len(powers) == n:
            break
    return powers[n-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Naming

`perfect` is quite general for a function name. A better choice might be something like `nth_perfect_power`.

#### Docstring comments

You have documented the function with a docstring comment, which is good. There is some repetition and verbosity however. I would perhaps use a single-line description, plus a description of what a perfect power is. You could also add some [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) examples:

```
def nth_perfect_power(n: int) -> int:
    """Return the n'th perfect power.

    A perfect power is a positive integer of the form m ** k with
    m >= 1 and k >= 2. Examples from https://oeis.org/A001597:

    >>> nth_perfect_power(1)
    1
    >>> nth_perfect_power(10)
    49
    >>> nth_perfect_power(50)
    1521
    """
```

Of course this is largely opinion-based.

#### Review and performance improvements

The initial assignment

```
i = 1
for i in range(0, n**2+1):
    // ...
        i += 1
```

has no effect, and incrementing `i` within the loop makes the logic difficult to understand. Perhaps this is done to take care of duplicate powers such as \$ 8^2 = 4^3 \$, but there are better approaches to solve that. You can for example move the check for a perfect power to a separate function (where you can early-return).

Apart from the first perfect power \$ i = 1 \$ one only needs to check values \$ m, k \ge 2 \$.

The length of the `powers` array needs only to be checked again if we added an element, not for each value of \$ i \$.

The last element of an array can be retrieved as `powers[-1]`.

Summarizing these topics so far, we get the following implementation:

```
def is_perfect_power(i: int) -> bool:
    if i == 1:
        return True
    for k in range(2, i):
        for m in range(2, i):
            if m ** k == i:
                return True
    return False

def nth_perfect_power(n: int) -> int:
    powers = []
    for i in range(1, n**2 + 1):
        if is_perfect_power(i):
            powers.append(i)
            if len(powers) == n:
                break
    return powers[-1]
```

This is more code than your original, but easier to read and slightly more efficient. It can be improved further: The exponentiation \$ m^k \$ can be replaced by repeated multiplication with \$ m \$. Also the inner loop can be exited as soon as a power is larger than the candidate \$ i \$:

```
def is_perfect_power(i: int) -> bool:
    if i == 1:
        return True
    for m in range(2, i):
        p = m * m
        while p < i:
            p *= m
        if p == i:
            return True
    return False
```

With these changes, the \$ 20^\text{th} \$ perfect power is found in approx. 3 milliseconds (compared to 2.6 seconds with your original code), and the \$ 100^\text{th} \$ perfect power is found in approx. 2.5 seconds.

#### A different approach

Your code determines for every candidate \$ i \$ if it is a perfect power by computing \$ m^k \$ for all \$ m, k \$ in the range \$ 0, \ldots, i \$. This is done for all \$i \$ up to  \$ n^2\$, until \$ n \$ perfect powers are found.

As an example, in order to find the \$ 20^\text{th} \$ perfect power, \$ m^k \$ is computed \$ 3382670\$ times.

We already improved that by restricting the base \$ m \$ and the exponent \$ k \$ to smaller ranges. But for larger values of \$ n \$ we need a different approach.

It is much more efficient to compute all perfect powers (in some range) instead, and then take the \$ n^\text{th} \$ smallest number. Since there can be duplicates (e.g. \$ 8^2 = 4^3 \$), a *set* should be used to collect the perfect powers.

You already used that there must be \$ n \$ perfect numbers in the range \$ 1, \ldots, n^2 \$. This can still be used to limit the range of the exponent \$ k \$.

As an example, in order to find the \$ 20^\text{th} \$ perfect power we need the numbers \$ m^k \$ in the range \$1, \ldots, 400 \$. The first perfect number \$ 1 \$ can be handled separately, so that \$ m \ge 2 \$ and \$ k \ge 2 \$:

$$
\begin{align}
 m&=2:  4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 \\
 m&=3: 9, 27, 81, 243 \\
 m&=4:  16, 64, 256 \\
 m&=5:  25, 125 \\
 m&=6:  35, 216 \\
 m&=7:  49, 343 \\
 m&=8:  64 \\
 \vdots \\
 m&=20: 400
\end{align}
$$

This leads to the following implementation:

```
def nth_perfect_power(n: int) -> int:
    upper_limit = n * n
    powers = set([1])
    for m in range(2, n + 1):
        p = m * m
        while p <= upper_limit:
            powers.add(p)
            p *= m
    return sorted(powers)[n-1]
```

This finds the \$ 100000^\text{th} \$ perfect power is found in approx. 0.1 seconds, and the one-millionth perfect power in approx. 1.4 seconds.

For even more performance, we can use a *heap* structure to store only the \$ n \$ smallest powers found so far. The Python `heapq` is a min-heap but we need a max-heap. Therefore all powers are multiplied by \$(-1)\$. We start with the list of squares and then add the third, fourth, ... powers. For every base \$ m \$ we can stop as soon as \$ p = m^k \$ is larger than the \$ n \$ smallest powers found so far.

Implementation:

```
def nth_perfect_power(n: int) -> int:
    heap = [- i * i for i in range(1, n+1)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    powers = set(heap)
    for m in range(2, n + 1):
        p = - m * m * m
        if p <= heap[0]:
            break
        while p > heap[0]:
            if not p in powers:
                powers.remove(heapq.heappushpop(heap, p))
                powers.add(p)
            p *= m
    return -heap[0]
```

This computes the one-millionth perfect power in approx. 0.42 seconds.

Comment: Your `powers` set could be written as a "one-liner", (not that doing so will make it any more readable). `powers = {1} | {m ** k for m in range(2, n+1) for k in range(2, floor(log(n*n,m)+1))}` .  Of course you need `from math import floor, log`.  Using \$\log_{m}{n^2}\$ as the upper limit of the range of `k` avoids the need to constantly test if p has exceeded n², and precomputing n² instead of calculating it every time would shave off a few microseconds too.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: You are totally right. I had thought of that but decided to keep it simple (and for n <= 100 it *probably* does not make a big difference).

Comment: @AJNeufeld: Precomputing n^2 also makes the code more self-documenting, so I have taken up your suggestion. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I'm getting a 21.8% speedup with the set-comprehension & \$log_{m}{n²}\$ method over your original method, on the 100,000th perfect power.  Still under a second for up to n = 600,000.

Comment: For the max-heap, you can use `heapq._heapify_max()`. And unless I'm thinking wrong, you could shave off a full iteration of the "heap-list" by building the heapq and the set in the same loop.

Comment: @ades: Is `heapq._heapify_max()` a documented feature? I had found that on SO but had the impression that it is an internal function (with the leading underscore). But I am not a Python expert, so I may be wrong here.

Comment: The `powers.remove(...)` is not necessary; just the `heapq.heappushpop(heap, p)`.  This reduces the time by 3% for perfect powers in the range 100,000 to 1,000,000, and by 5% for the 20th perfect power.  Also, changing all occurrences of `heap[0]` to `limit`, and adding `limit = heap[0]` before the `for m` loop and in the `if not p` statement reduces the time by 6%, 8%, and 15% for the 1,000,000, the 100,000 and the 20th perfect powers, respectively.  (And no, `heapq._heapify_max()` is not documented)

Comment: @AJNeufeld: I had removed the numbers from the set in order to limit its size. But  I can confirm that not removing them improves the performance. With respect to holding the current `limit` in a separate variable my results are not clear, running the code with  n=20 multiple times it is sometimes faster and sometimes slower. – Are you planning to post your suggestions as an answer?

Comment: If I had improvements on the OP's code, I'd post an answer.  But all I have are performance tweaks on your answer, so I wasn't planning to post effectively the same answer, plagiarizing your improvements with minor tweaks for eeking out every last possible performance cycle.